# Running my Symfony Application on Heroku : "There are no commands defined in the "server" namespace. "

Tags: heroku, symfony4

Ok, so this is my first question on any forum ever but I'll try to be as clear as possible...
I've been working on Symfony for a while now, both at work and for a personal project at home. However, I'd never deployed any application whatsoever until now. I chose Heroku to deploy my personal Symfony project, and I did every step as told in the docs :
1. I create an Heroku app
2. I linked it to my local repository
Then I did :

```
heroku config:set SYMFONY_ENV=prod
```

This wasn't enough to make the build succeed so I had to do

```
heroku config:set APP_ENV=prod
```

too but any way it ended up deploying

Then I set up the database with JAWSDB, and ran :

```
heroku run "php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate"
```

I now have access to a prod database with the right structure so I know my code is working

What is the problem then ? The url to my app is showing a 404, whatever the endpoint I use, and when I try to access it from my front local app, (**it is after all, an API**), I have a CORS problem, so the Options request returns a 200 and then nothing. I know it's not about CORS because I set them to accept *.

The thing is, I think my app is not running on Heroku...I never told heroku in anyway how to run it so it would be logical

***I haven't used docker***, so the only piece of information I told heroku was with this command :

```
echo 'web: $(composer config bin-dir)/heroku-php-apache2 public/' > Procfile
```

I'm not entirely sure what it does but I don't think it has something to do with my problem

So I thought I'd start the server from the heroku bash, and I ran :

```
heroku run "php bin/console server:start"
```

considering that 'php bin/console server:start' is the way I start it loccally, it looked like a good thing to do

But I had this error :  **There are no commands defined in the "server" namespace.**

I looked it up on the internet, and ended up finding a note about this command not being available on prod environment...

I have absolutely no idea how to run my app on heroku, and I don't even know precisely what I am looking for, considering the fact that all the tutorials seem to suppose you just have to deploy and open...

I can't see what I'm missing, and that's what decided me in writing this first and very long (sorry) post on StackOverflow

Thanks for reading until the end,

Coline

Answer (score 0):

So this line:

```
web: $(composer config bin-dir)/heroku-php-apache2 public/
```

in your `Procfile` tells Heroku to run Apache and point it at the `public` directory. This (or another webserver like nginx, which Heroku also supports) is the production replacement for `php bin/console server:start` (which is, as you've discovered, only for local development use).

You shouldn't need the `server:start` at all on Heroku. If your application isn't running after ensuring you've added and deployed your `Procfile` as part of the repository, something else is going on.

Heroku provides [documentation for getting a Symfony app running](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-symfony). Make sure you've followed their steps.

Comment: I'm sure I deployed the Procfile, I have absolutely no doubt about that...And the documentation you are pointing me to is the one I followed :/ Thanks for you answer anyway !

Comment: I tried by following the tutorial with a brand new Symfony project and it worked, but it is in Symfony 3.0, and I am using Symfony 4.3 and I don't want to go back to 3.0

Comment: OMG it worked ! I'm not sure how because I tried and reverted so many things ! I think the solution was "composer require symfony/apache-pack" I'm almost sure it is the only thing I did and not reverted. I hope it helps someone